# ELB Listener protocol and certificate is getting reset

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb

I exposed web services for some pods through kubernetes. The ELB's got successfully created for these services. I have modified the listener protocol for these services to HTTPS and HTTP from TCP. Changed ports and certificates accordingly. The ELB is up and running without any issues.

But, after every 2 days, I saw, the protocols and certificates are getting reset to initial state. When I'm doing the required changes, the web-service is up again.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason to this and how can this be solved??

Comment: If kubernetes itself created the ELB, then it's probably reverting the changes. Make your changes inside the kubernetes manifests. There are annotations for changing ELB settings.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm, I set the values through annotations in kubernetes manifests and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using ALB-ingress-controller.
ALB ingress controller resets it to the setting defined in ALB ingress.

You can set certificates and rules using ingress only using `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn` and `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions` annotations.
Doing this way, your changes won't revert.

https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/ingress/annotation/